# How to add a Map to RequestBody instead of adding key value pairs individually when using okhttp?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

If I have this:

```
RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
            .add("email", "Jurassic@Park.com")
            .add("tel", "90301171XX")
            .build();
```

But instead of adding key value pairs individually, I just want to add a variable of type map that has a variable size, how do I go about adding it?

Comment: how about using a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just iterating over the map yourself and adding each key/value? Example:

```
private FormEncodingBuilder makeBuilderFromMap(final Map<String, String> map) {
    FormEncodingBuilder formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : map.entrySet()) {
        formBody.add(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
    }
    return formBody;
}
```

usage:

```
RequestBody body = makeBuilderFromMap(map)
  .otherBuilderStuff()
  .otherBuilderStuff()
  .otherBuilderStuff()
  .build();
```

Comment: That's not possible. You need to build the object (`RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder().build();`) at the time of instantiation, and once built, you can't add.

Comment: Oh okay, I wasn't sure, I haven;t used RequestBody. My bad.

Comment: it was a good point to start ... what about new version? (of course i would prefer `makeBuilderFromMap` static member of  `FormEncodingBuilderUtils` class) by `otherBuilderStuff()` i mean set headers or other builder stuff :)

Comment: This is not helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you do the typing correctly the code provided by nbokmans works well. Here the corrected version:

```
private RequestBody makeFormBody(final Map<String, String> map) {
    FormEncodingBuilder formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder();
    for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entrySet : map.entrySet()) {
        formBody.add(entrySet.getKey(), entrySet.getValue());
    }
    return formBody.build();
}
```

Comment: instead of copy-pasting an answer to fix the issues in it, it is more common to point out the errors as comments to the answer. No need to duplicate things.